# dereferencing pointer to a pointer

Tags: c, pointers, dereference

given the following code

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct Foo {
  int **bar;
}Foo;


int main(){
  Foo *foo = malloc(sizeof(Foo));
  foo->bar = malloc(sizeof(int**));
  int *tmp = malloc(sizeof(int)*2);
  tmp[0]= 0;
  tmp[1]=1;
  *(foo->bar) = tmp;
  //printf("%d",*(foo->bar)[1]);  <=== This line                                                                                                                                                                                   
  int *tmp2 = *(foo->bar);
  printf("%d ",tmp2[1]);

  return 0;
}
```

The line commented out causes a segmentation fault.

Can some one please explain what is actually happening?

Why is that line and the next print statement not equivalent?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`> Can some one please explain what is actually happening?`

It's an [operation precedence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence) problem:

```
printf("%d",(*(foo->bar))[1]); // <=== This is what you wanted
```

Note the extra parens grouping the deference of the `foo->bar` before the `[1]`, you need to do this because the subscripting (`[]`) operator has higher precedence than the dereference (`*`) operator

`> Why is that line and the next print statement not equivalent?`

Because by breaking up the statements you took care of the order of operations issue, you made the lower precedence operation occur first:

```
int *tmp2 = *(foo->bar);
```

Answer (score 2):

The array indexing operator `[]` has a higher precedence than the deference `*` operator. So, that line means "deference the `int *` at index 1 of the `foo->bar` array". But of course, you only have an array of 1 `int *` (index 0), so a seg fault results.